# Can't chromecast when connected to OpenVPN

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, chromecast

I have installed OpenVPN on a remote server and everything is working fine. I have a chromecast and I can cast on it when connected to the VPN server from my computer but not from my Android phone. The chromecast is still detected by the phone though but the casting doesn't work.

I've used OpenVPN-AS to setup the config of the VPN. I've added the directive 'push "route 192.168.0.0 255.255.0.0 net_gateway"' in /etc/openvpn/server.conf but it doesn't change anything. Do you have any idea of what could be the problem?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you running the client app as root?

Comment: No, my phone isn't rooted, do you think the app hasn't the right to add the route?

Comment: Would be my guess, or that its adding it only for certain protocols (it sees the CC's announces). The networking stack in android is not something I really have any knowledge about. Question might do better migrated to android community on the exchange network.